# textvariables in Tkinter for Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using a tkinter Entry widget in a temporary window to collect information from a user.  I want to be able to use that information for a variety of things: rewrite it in a Label in another window, convert it to an integer for calculations, get its value as a string for writing to a file, and so on.  In this stripped down code, I've got two text variables, and I've used quotation marks to name one and not the other.  As I understand it, using the quotation marks is wrong--the variable without the quotation marks works correctly with get, for example.  The trouble is that the one without the quotation marks doesn't copy correctly when I use it as the textvariable for a Label in a different window.  What am I missing here?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

sheetid = StringVar
sheetname = StringVar

def dosheet():
    sheet = Toplevel(root)
    ttk.Label(sheet, text="Sheet ID:").grid(row=0)
    ttk.Label(sheet, textvariable=sheetid, font=(11)).grid(row=1)
    ttk.Label(sheet, text="Sheet Name:").grid(row=2)
    ttk.Label(sheet, textvariable="sheetname", font=(11)).grid(row=3)
#end dosheet

def new():
    def finish():
        start.destroy()
        dosheet()

    start = Toplevel(root)
    start.title("New sheet dialog")
    ttk.Label(start, text="Sheet ID:").grid(row=1)
    ttk.Entry(start, textvariable=sheetid).grid(row=2)
    ttk.Label(start, text="Sheet name:").grid(row=3)
    ttk.Entry(start, textvariable="sheetname").grid(row=4)
    ttk.Button(start, text="Close", command=finish).grid(row=5)
#end new

main = ttk.Frame(root, padding="16 12 12 12")
main.grid()

ttk.Label(main, text="Start new sheet:").grid()
ttk.Button(main, text="New", command=new).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say *"The trouble is that the one without the quotation marks doesn't copy correctly when I use it as the textvariable for a Label in a different window."*? The word "copy" doesn't make sense in this context. And what do you mean when you say it is not correct? Are the letters jumbled? Are some letters missing?

Comment: I pushed the new button and entered numbers for the two Entry boxes.  The Close button then creates a window that uses those two numbers.  Then I pushed New again and typed in different numbers.  When I push Close, the new window does not have any number for sheetid, but "sheetname" does match what I just typed into the Entry box.

I either solved the problem or found a workaround.  My new code uses Entry variables in1 and in2 and Label variables out1 and out2.  The Close button uses sheetid=in1.get() and out1.set(sheetid).  The variables have to be declared global in the function defs.

Comment: Now I feel pretty stupid.  sheetid=StringVar doesn't work, but sheetid=StringVar() does.  First law of computer code: quote syntax verbatim even if you don't understand it.

Comment: @GlennLedder I have elaborated my problem  in this question :- 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866581/how-to-use-stringvar-and-display-the-value-inserted-in-a-tkinter-entry
Please looking for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
# with () you call the class to create a new object (instance) of it.
sheetid = StringVar('sheetid')
sheetname = StringVar('sheetname') 



def dosheet():
    #                             remove "
    ttk.Label(sheet, textvariable=sheetname, font=(11)).grid(row=3)
```

What does it do?

Comment: **bold** sheetid = StringVar('sheetid') **bold** produces a syntax error.