# How to use StringVar and display the value inserted in a Tkinter Entry?

Tags: python, tkinter

Scenario is something like this:- I created a label named as **Username** and created a Entry  as **entry1** withe the code like below. And I created another label **Label2** where I want to display the same value inserted above in *entry1*. Code is something like below:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

test=StringVar()

label1=Label(root,text='Username').grid()
entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=test)
entry1.grid()

#print test
button1 = Button(root, text = 'Login',).grid()

label2=Label(root,textvariable= test).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

PS: This is the code I am working with, I am a newbie in Python and Tkinter so please suggest the easiest approach.

Comment: So what is wrong with the code you have?  Can you provide a simple, minimal working example that we can play with?  e.g. your sample code doesn't define root, doesn't enter the mainloop anywhere, etc.

Comment: Side note, in your example code, `button1`, `label1` and `label2` will all have the value of `None` since that is what `Widget.grid` returns.

Comment: See also [Python TkInter - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1101750/953482), regarding assignment and `grid`

Comment: @mgilson I have edited the code and now this is the code that I am using. Would you please go through the code and help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @algosig -- your code works for me (When I type in the entry, stuff appears in the label).

Comment: @mgilson I am now a joke to ask the question which is totally right, 
Just workde after I restarted the text editor and the terminal. I don't know what kind of error was that.

Comment: @algosig -- No problem, the question will probably get closed because it "can't be reproduced due to a typographical error".  The fact that it is a close option shows that this sort of thing happens A LOT.  Alternatively, you can choose to delete the question if you'd rather (look for the "delete" button under the post).